# Asynchronous resultset in Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, jtds

I'm a newbie to Android and Java. My first application consists of 7-8 activities and instead of creating a web service, I have chosen to directly connect to SQL Server 2008 database via jTDS. I'm not storing any data, except preferences, on the device.

At first, I've stuck with NetworkOperationOnMainThread exception. And created a custom listview adapter, a spinner adapter and jTDS wrapper that pools query requests, runs asynchronously and returns resultsets to listener. Each listener, upon triggering of completion event, first checks for the task Id to see if it's the one we'd been waiting for, then extracts the resultset.My custom SpinnerAdapter is also implementing this interface. My aim is, basically, to populate the spinner items from remote database.

This ran well, after some painful debugging and learning process. But, since this ResultSet relies on a server-side cursor, whenever I call the .next() method, it throws the same NetworkOperationOnMainThread exception.

How would you recommend me to move on? What I got on my mind is, copying the ResultSet object to local objects somehow. Though it wouldn't be a problem for tens of records, but what if I have to populate a listview with thousands?

Another option I'm evaluating is, extending the jTDS wrapper class' functionality to run .next() async, too. Troublesome, too. I should do this to any method running on ResultSet.

On the other hand, since Android wants all actions that's not related to UI in a background thread no matter if the database is remote or local, everyone should be facing this, and should already be a workaround. Feeling like trying to invent the wheel again.

Regards,

Comment: what about AsyncQueryHandler ?

Comment: also you can combine AQH with a AbstractWindowedCursor

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to stick with accessing data over the network, then you should wrap your database access using the `Loader` [1](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex) interface. Coupled with the `LoaderManager`[2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html) you can take advantage of Android's new framework for working with Loaders when accessing and delivering data in an asynchronous way.

There is a library that you can look at as a guide that implements the `Loader` interface for asynchronous SQLite database access on the device. The library can be found [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex).

**References**

1. [Loader](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Loader.html)
2. [LoaderManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html)
3. [cwac-loaderex](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex)

Comment: Hi. Correct me if I'm wrong but the library does not have a select task. And Loader API based on Cursor not ResultSet, and jTDS rely on ResultSet. Either I need to implement Cursor interface on ResultSet, which does not makes sense.

Comment: I guess that instead of trying to make something generic, I'll stick to a high-level solution, specific to the current database schema. Like, defining a contract class including query Ids for each query task. And, it's going to connect, query and parse resultset into objects in a background thread. Maybe I could utilize some reflection for generic conversion of resultset into list of objects.